# What is the need of Alt Texts to image?

Tags: seo

Can anyone explain me what is the use of Alt Texts to images.

Answer (score 2):

`alt` is a required attribute in HTML for the `<img>` tag. The text inside is used in place of an image should the image be missing or the browser, such as a screen reader, cannot view the image. It's helpful for accessibility, that is, users who are blind or otherwise unable to view your image, too.

Answer (score 1):

Alt Tags or Alt Attributes are “alternative text” for an image and are never seen by people reading your website. These tags are simply used for search engines. When search engines crawl your website they use the alt tags to better understand the content of your website so that they can properly index it within the ranks of their search results. If the images on your website are optimized with the right keywords you can drive a lot of that search traffic to your website. Properly optimized images with right alt tags can make a huge impact on the number of people who visit your website on a regular basis.

The biggest benefits that you will receive from optimizing your images with alt tags and title tags are as follows:

- Increased search traffic to your website
- Higher quality search traffic to your website
- More engaged website visitors

Comment: **Your first two sentences are absolutely false!** https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/images.html#alt

Comment: You have to ask, What came first? Image alt text is intended for the blind and text only browsers. Search engines using the text followed. It is only used for image search and will not help a page perform in search. It is analyzed for semantic meaning for indexing images and relevancy to the content as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google robots cannot read image. The alt help them. You should write to  what is on the image. 
It's one part of SEO-optimization.